# Invalid manifest

Tags: google-apps-script, manifest, google-apps-marketplace

When I try to save appscript.json, I get this error message.

Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [api_console_project_id]

My manifest/appscript file looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "api_console_project_id": "App ID"
}
```

I can confirm that Google Apps Marketplace SDK is enabled.

I'm using the online script editor.

Comment: You have `api_console_project_id` in a first level category, but there is no category for `api_console_project_id`  The only category that the Marketplace SDK would be in, is "dependencies -> enabledAdvancedServices"  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  If you want to publish an add-on to the Apps Marketplace, you don't need anything special in the manifest file.  I have an add-on published to the Apps Marketplace, and there is nothing in the manifest file for the Marketplace SDK.  [Docs Manifest Structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#manifest_structure)

Comment: @SandyGood I do, when I click publish, it throws an error and says: There is no API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field.

Comment: I would delete `"api_console_project_id": "App ID"` from your manifest, and the comma on the preceding line, and save the manifest file.

Comment: I did and it gives me that error I was describing. @SandyGood

Comment: I'm not sure what the solution is.  Can you create a file that works, and look at the manifest and then compare?

Comment: @gal007 No, I can't solve the problem, that's the whole reason I put this question up on stack overflow. Sorry :-(